# Is there a shortcut key to move a code selection left or right in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to achieve the same action that Alt+up/down does, to left and right movement of a code selection.
for example,
if I have this code `an[]` if I select `n` and press a shortcut to move it right it should become `a[n]`. Is there any shortcut for this? If not, is there a way to custom define this?

I use Eclipse Luna.

Comment: You can try to add a new command like this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_key-binding_configuration%3F and assign a shortcut

Comment: There's no such a function, as far as I know. Perhaps you should edit by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to do that. if you look at the General > Keys in preferences, you can see that there are only commands for Move Lines Up and Move Lines Down.

So you have to keep going with drag & drop.

Comment: okay then is there a way to custom define the behaviour that I want?

Comment: I dont know if there is another way to do this, but you can check this: [PracticalMacro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/). Good Luck @VivekVK